# Visual Studio 2022 Pro hangs when adding, renaming or deleting files

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 Pro hangs when adding, renaming, pasting in or deleting files. I have to end-task Visual Studio and restart it to be able to finish the process. It's soul destroying when you're trying to develop and have to keep end-tasking your development environment every time you add a new file. It's also not unusual to lose unsaved work if you forget to save before triggering the hang.

There is an open bug for this issue - but it needs upvoting to get Microsoft to take it seriously and fix it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-studio-2022-hangs-when-pasting-in/1701816

[image: The hang is clearly caused by calls to the Team Foundation Server (in our case Azure dev ops)]

[image: Blocked threads causing the issue]

Does anyone have a work-around? If not - please have pity on everyone affected by this issue and click the link above to up-vote it so Microsoft fixes it. (You may need to open Visual Studio, and click on Help --> Send Feedback --> My Feedback to get logged in so you can upvote)

People affected by this issue have already tried reinstalling / repairing Visual Studio. This does not fix the issue, you just lose all your settings. We have also reported the bug to Microsoft with memory dumps, crash hang analysis and screen-shots - but it's not getting fixed.

Comment: What version control are you using? TFVC (old style TFS) or git repos?

Comment: We are connected to dev.azure.com - TFS - not git. We really don't want to switch to git repos - we don't like how they work.

Comment: Most of Microsoft's tooling is aimed towards git these days, wouldn't be surprised if they stopped supporting TFVC altogether sometime in the future. Curious to know why you don't like how git repos work.

Comment: I don't mind if they stop supporting TFVC on azure devops providing they migrate all our current source control over automatically - or at least provide a tool do to it. If it has to be done manually, then its a non-starter for us. In the interim, they really need to fix the bugs. It's just a preference - I've been using TFVC for years.